# custom error page from web.config not being called

Tags: iis-7, .net

i've setup custom errors for all non .NET pages using the IIS error pages module and those work fine.

i have added the  tag to the web.config file for all the .net application folders.  this should handle any error that is encountered when a user tries to open a .net (.aspx) page within that folder.  It seems simple to setup, and it was working when i first set it up. Now, after a server reboot, it won't work anymore.

The web.config file is:

i have also tried a hard-coded path in the web.config.

The folder is setup as a .net application folder with the application pool = ASP.NET v4.0

I can browse directly to the error.aspx and 404.aspx files and open them successfully from the browser window.

www.mydomain.com/testingDotNet/404.aspx  and www.mydomain.com/testingDotNet/error.aspx  will load fine with no errors.

But when I try to open a non-existent page:

### www.mydomain.com//testingDotNet/nopage.aspx ==> this should call 404.aspx  but instead i get the .net 404 page:

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

### Requested URL: /testingDotNet/nopage.aspx

I ran a failed request trace, but i can't really decipher anything from that.  The results, with code section just before error display are:
Failure Reason  STATUS_CODE
Trigger Status  404
Final Status    404
131.        NOTIFY_MODULE_START

ModuleName="CustomErrorModule", Notification="SEND_RESPONSE", fIsPostNotification="false", fIsCompletion="false"

```
19:30:02.278
```

132.        GENERAL_NOT_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR

Reason="SETSTATUS_TRYSKIP"

```
19:30:02.278
```

133.        NOTIFY_MODULE_END

ModuleName="CustomErrorModule", Notification="SEND_RESPONSE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"

```
19:30:02.278
```

134.    i   HTTPSYS_CACHEABLE

HttpsysCacheable="false", Reason="NO_PIPELINE_ENABLE", CachePolicy="NO_CACHE", TimeToLive="0"

```
19:30:02.278
```

135.    i   GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START
    19:30:02.278
136.    i   GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS

Headers="Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
"

```
19:30:02.278
```

137.        GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER

Buffer="
    
        The resource cannot be found.

I get this same response page whether i make a call to the page remotely or on the server itself.  i would expect the custom page to show up on the call from a remote machine, since the customerror mode is set to "RemoteOnly".  But the behavior does not change, even if i turn mode to"Off".

this seems like a pretty simple task.  and oddly, it worked when i first configured it, and now it won't work.  i've stopped and restarted IIS, and restarted the server.  it's making me think i'm crazy!  any help on why this may be happening is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found over time that everything the custom errors don't work, it's almost always because something else in the web.config file is off.  The troubleshoot, try a bare bones web.config with the customErrors set.  That may do it.  Then start adding parts of your web.config back until you get it working.  Watch for inheritance conflicts between the root and subfolders too.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems I had two problems:  First was mixing absolute and relative paths in the <customerrors> section of the web config.  I stripped everything but customerrors tag  and one <error> tag for 404.  Set all paths from the root using /foldername/404.aspx.   Second problem was setting response.statuscode in the body of the error page.  it was hitting the 404.aspx page, then setting the response, then redirecting to the global error page.  I set the customerrors attribute redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" and moved the response.write after the close <html> in 404.aspx.  Life is good!

Comment: Excellent, glad you tracked it down and have it working now. Thanks for the update.